# Button hiding the text field when the I run the app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginner to android studio.I am creating a simple project where clicking on a button changes text in the text field. The problem is that when I run the app the button is covering the text field and hiding the text on it.So I am not able to view the text change or even the default text.In the main xml file,the button is underneath the text field,which is how I want it to look.Can anyone help? Problem with the layout setting?

Comment: Please post your code snippets.

Comment: When you visit the doctor, do you just tell her that your body hurts and expect her to know exactly how to help you? No, you tell her what part of your body hurts and give details if the symptoms you experience. Similarly, we need more details in order to help. See [mcve] for suggestions for how to provide those details.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your button tag

```
android:layout_toEndOf = "@+id/textviewid"
```

That it now your button will display below your textview

Answer (score 0):

**Try this layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Click!"
        android:textAllCaps="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```